# how to deal with functions with a variable number of parameters?

Tags: c, string, function

I need to create a function that outputs all words from the given strings in which the given letter is repeated three or more times, without using `<stdarg>`

I've tried this code below, but something's going wrong, can you tell me, please, how to fix this issue?  The program is working in some way, but not exactly right, so I think, I can go without macros.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int count_char(char* str, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    c = 'o';
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == c) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void print_words(unsigned k, char* str, ...) {
    char* word;
    char* p;
    int i;
    const char* delim = " ,.;:!?\t\n\r\f\v";
    for (i = 0, p = str; i < k; p++) {
        word = strtok(p, delim);
        while (word != NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
                int char_count = count_char(word, word[i]);
                if (char_count >= 3) {
                    printf("Words with repeated letter: %s\n", word);
                    break;
                }
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
          
        }
    }

}

int main() {
        char str1[] = "This is a sampooole sentenceoooo.";
        char str2[] = "Another sentence, with more woooords.";
        print_words(2, str1, str2);
        return 0;
}
```

This is the ouput I've got:

```
    Words with repeated letter: sampooole
    Words with repeated letter: sentenceoooo.
    Words with repeated letter: sampooole
    Words with repeated letter: ampooole
    Words with repeated letter: mpooole
    Words with repeated letter: pooole
    Words with repeated letter: ooole
    Words with repeated letter: sentenceoooo
    Words with repeated letter: entenceoooo
    Words with repeated letter: ntenceoooo
    Words with repeated letter: tenceoooo
    Words with repeated letter: enceoooo
    Words with repeated letter: nceoooo
    Words with repeated letter: ceoooo
    Words with repeated letter: eoooo
    Words with repeated letter: oooo
    Words with repeated letter: ooo
    Words with repeated letter: woooords.
    Words with repeated letter: woooords
    Words with repeated letter: oooords
    Words with repeated letter: ooords
```

Comment: What does the problem you observe have to do with variable number of function arguments?

Comment: "Without using `<stdarg.h>`..." Why does the shown code have `#include <stdarg.h>` (PS: _Usually_ the 2nd call to `strtok()` uses the same delimiter string as the first.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 directly - none, but still there is a problem in something, and I am asking for advice on what exactly

Comment: @Fe2O3    yeah, i just forgot to delete  this line

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have this problem if you only use functions with fixed numbers of arguments?

Comment: The outer `for()` loop keeps presenting shorter versions of the same string (that has been mangled during the first iteration... What is the purpose of the outer `for()` loop?

Comment: If you want to use variable arguments, you **must** use the `stdarg` functions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is how you're using `strtok` inside the `print_words` function. Try using a copy of the input string and then tokenizing the copy because `strtok` modifies the original and could lead to corruption. Try replacing the `print_words` function with this:

```c
void print_words(unsigned k, char* str, ...) {
    char* word;
    char* p;
    int i;
    const char* delim = " ,.;:!?\t\n\r\f\v";
    char *str_cpy = strdup(str);             // Copied string here
    for (i = 0, p = str; i < k; p++) {
        word = strtok(str_cpy, delim);       // Strtok copied string
        while (word != NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
                int char_count = count_char(word, word[i]);
                if (char_count >= 3) {
                    printf("Words with repeated letter: %s\n", word);
                    break;
                }
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, delim);      
          
        }
    }
    free(str_cpy);
}
```